# How to access nested Map entry items in stream?

Tags: java, collections

I have a nested `Map` object as this:

```
Map<String,Map<Integer,Double>> items = getMap();
```

I have a class named `MyClass` that its constructor is as this:

```
public MyClass(String city, int month, double average){}
```

Now I want to convert `items` to `MyClass` list as this:

```
List<MyClass> myList = items.entrySet().stream()
                                       .map(i-> new MyClass(i.getKey(), ?, ?))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but I don't know what should I use instead of `?` to access nested `Integer` and `Double` values from `Map` object?

Comment: Is it that `Map<Integer,Double>` contains just a single entry?

Comment: @ernest_k No, zero or more items may be exist.

Comment: Then I think @user7's solution should work for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have a nested map, you have to process the inner map entries too.
(this is assuming there are many month-average pairs for a city)

```
List<MyClass> myList = items.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(innerEntry -> new MyClass(entry.getKey(), innerEntry.getKey(), innerEntry.getValue()))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very compact way without streams, yet using Java 8 features:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
items.forEach((city, innerMap) -> innerMap.forEach(month, average) -> 
                                  myList.add(new MyClass(city, month, average)));
```